# Log4j stops logging after a while

Tags: jboss, log4j

I'm using log4j as logging system under JBOSS 5.
Randomly and after a while (always impredicible) it stops writting in the log file. My root loggers are CONSOLE and FILE and my FILE appender is a DailyRollingFileAppender.
When it stops, the only way to make it log again is to re-save the jboss-log4j.xml file under /conf. I resave it with a blank space and after 60 secs (as defined in jmx-console jboss.system log4j ) it starts logging again. Unfortunately, it stops after some time.
Have anyone of you had this issue before? Please, let me know if you need more info so that I can provide you with.

Comment: I experience this problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/abc.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This works for me.